# Invoke hangs Winforms app in х64 mode and very seldom in x32

Tags: .net, winforms

There are two kinds of thread in my app - UI (exactly 1 instance) and non-UI (several). 
I have a scenario when app gets hanged in Control.Invoke when UI thread  executes Application.DoEvents.

I do emphasize - UI-thread always executes message pump.

1. App working better if I call Invoke via mainform, not child control
2. BeginInvoke works fine (Post)
3. BeginInvoke hangs when I add AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne (Send)
4. **Everything works fine under Remote Desktop (sic!)**
5. х32 works much better than x64

Is there a proper fix fix ?  I'm very reluctant to write my own dispatcher.

Is there a good dispatcher that independent from Winforms ?

UPD:
x32 version gets hanged very seldom. x64 gets hanged much often and I've got only one scenario when it gets hanged regularly.
And as I said, app under RDP works excelent !

UPD2:
Delegate isn't called when neither Invoke nor BeginInvoke are used

P.S. There is a bug in connect mictrosoft, but it marked as fixed
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/97166/control-invoke-hangs

Piece of code from myApp:

```
        //UI-thread
        while (!m_longOperationContext.FinishEvent.WaitOne(100, false))
        {
          System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
          Trace.WriteLine("Waiting..."); // this I see in the output
        }

        //non-UI thread
        ctrl.Invoke(new Action(() => // this call sometimes hangs despite the UI-thread always executes message pump
        {
            SomeOperation(ctrl);
        }));
```

Comment: Well, never use DoEvents and never call WaitOne on the UI thread.  Take it from there.

Comment: I have to use because I need to execute some operations on UI-thread. The thing is that only given call of Invoke hangs the application, and the rest of them work fine.

Comment: Revise your design. The code you pasted does not show how "ugly" the full image is, but unless you use a proper design, you cannot easily avoid the hangs. Besides, don't consider every case you hit a .NET bug. In most cases you have to write advanced level code so as to hit one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is .Net bug, because 1 when I call invoke via  parent of the control all works fine 2 under RDP all is fine 3 x32 hangs very seldom

Comment: If you are so confident, then the only way to get it resolve is to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to actively challenge Microsoft. Or you have to open a new issue on Microsoft Connect and passively wait for a reply. Good luck.

Comment: You are right. But I have to use framework 3.5 when ms connect accepts bug on 4.0 and 4.5 version. I can't use 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but i have encountered this today.
It happens very rarely so i cant reproduce it. But i have found a solution that seems to work.

```
private delegate void ArticleListThreadHandler();
private void OnOrderArticleSyncFinished()
    {
        //if (this.InvokeRequired)
        //{
        //    IAsyncResult result = BeginInvoke(new ArticleListThreadHandler(OnOrderArticleSyncFinished));
        //    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        //}
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            ThreadStart myMethod = delegate { OnOrderArticleSyncFinished(); };
            this.BeginInvoke(myMethod);
            return;
        }
        else
            PopulateArticleList();
    }
```

The code i commented out sometimes made the calling thread hang. When i changed it to the uncommented code i haven't run into the issue anymore.

It seem the code only hang when called from another thread...and not always :/

This is the error i get when i close the application when the bug has occurred.

System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeWaitHandle waitHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int64 timeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne()
   at xyz.ServiceEdition.Modules.Article.ArticleList.OnOrderArticleSyncFinished()
   at xyz.ServiceEdition.Modules.Article.ArticleModule.SyncFinishedEventHandler.Invoke()
   at xyz.ServiceEdition.Modules.Article.ArticleModule.OnSyncFinished()
   at xyz.Modules.SyncModule.SyncStateDelegate.Invoke()
   at xyz.Modules.SyncModule.MobileSyncModule.SendSyncFinished()

Hopefully this can help someone :)